# Access DB: Operation must use an updateable query

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, oledb

I am running an ISS server, i have an access file located in C:\WCF\Access\
I am using this query to insert something:

```
@"INSERT INTO Arbejdsindsats (MedarYdelID, StartTid, SlutTid) VALUES ('" + medarYdelID + "', '" + startTid + "', '" + slutTid + "')";
```

The full code is:

```
public String GemArbejdsIndsats(String medarYdelID, String startTid, String slutTid)
        {
            try{
            con.Open();
            String command = @"INSERT INTO Arbejdsindsats (MedarYdelID, StartTid, SlutTid) VALUES ('" + medarYdelID + "', '" + startTid + "', '" + slutTid + "')";
            cmd.CommandText = command;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();


                return "success: medarydelid: " + medarYdelID + " startTid: " + startTid + " slutTid: " + slutTid;
            } catch(Exception e)
                {
                    String k = e.Message;
                    return k;
                }
        }
```

The problem is this error:

> Operation must use an updateable query

When i test locally on my own machine, it works fine. Just not in the IIS.

The weird thing is that there's a laccdb file. it wont go away. Maybe the database is locked and thats why i cant update it?

The permission should not be a problem:

[img http://img.ctrlv.in/50c0dbf8670d8.jpg](http://img.ctrlv.in/50c0dbf8670d8.jpg)

Comment: Are you closing your connection after insert is complete?

Comment: Yes i do. The code works locally.

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: What permissions does the `IUSR` account have on the accdb and laccdb files and on the folder where they are located?

Comment: This will sound stupid, but do you have this table or database open curently in MS Access on your system. It doesnt look like it is the program thats locking the file, it could be caused from someone else having the file open.

Comment: Thank you for your help Derek and HansUp. The issue has been resolved.

Comment: in my case accdb file was in opened condition with access,  I closed the file and issue resolved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user account must be able to write to the files and to the folder in which they are located; it should be able to create and delete files in the folder.  The presence of the laccdb file does not necessarily mean that access has locked the database.  Its presence could be the result of any of several circumstances, one of which could be that the user account doesn't have permission to delete files from the folder.

Comment: I knew that. But now it's working. I desperately gave full access to everything, the access file folder, the folder above, the access file, the lock file and the website folder.
The issue seem to be solved now. thank you

Answer (score 1):

solution of this issue is pretty simple. just run that application as administrator. i tried it 3 times and it worked perfectly

Comment: This is true, so +1, but I would note that this simple solution works because administrator privileges by default allow the creation and deletion of files.  Running the application as administrator is contrary to best practices, however, so some IT departments will not be happy with the simple approach; knowing about the directory permissions angle is therefore helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Also,  Make sure the file is not Read Only.