# PHP/MS ACCESS Local User can write to DB but remote users cannot

Tags: php, ms-access, authentication, iis, windows-authentication

I am setting up a site that takes data from users and puts it into Database. I am using MS Access since this would only be used by 20-30 colleagues. The site is deployed using IIS 7.5 on localhost:92  The firewall rules have been enabled to allow connection on port 80-95 (Since there are sites on ports and some ports are used for testing sites).

For Authentication I have enabled Windows Authentication only and limited the users through authorization rules.

It is running on a Desktop where the Website and Access File (Access 2010 accdb files are stored in My Documents. I have given the access rights to IIS_IUSRS)

So when I open the site and enter data it successfully goes into the database. But when any colleague tries with their PC it gives error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -3035 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access 
Driver] Operation must use an updateable query. (SQLExecute[-3035] at 
ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)' in 
C:\Users\username\Documents\Website\website\index.html:139 
(file:///C:/Users/username/Documents/Website/website/index.html:139) Stack 
trace: #0 C:\Users\username\Documents\Website\website\index.html(139) 
(file:///C:/Users/username/Documents/Website/website/index.html(139)): PDO-
>query('INSERT INTO Tab...') #1 {main} thrown in 
C:\Users\username\Documents\Website\website\index.html 
(file:///C:/Users/username/Documents/Website/website/index.html) on line 139
```

I tried sharing the folder with everyone.There is no lock on the DB. I gave permissions of ODBC Registry keys to IIS_IUSRS. I gave DB Folder Permissions to everyone. Tried by giving permission to specific users also. Did not work.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$conn = 
    'odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' .
    'Dbq=C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Website\\Database\\Change.accdb;;ReadOnly=0';

$dbh = new PDO($conn);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$Change=$_POST["change"];
$Name=$_POST["name1"];
$Inc=$_POST["inc"];
$Waiver=$_POST["waiver"];
$Support=$_POST["support"];
$Environment=$_POST["environment"];
$Attachment=$_POST["attach"];
$SapID=$_POST["sapid"];
$Schedule=$_POST["schedule"];
$ChangeType=$_POST["type"];
$AffectedCI=$_POST["affect"];
$Risk=$_POST["risk"];
$Ref=$_POST["ref"];
$Priority=$_POST["priority"];
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE UserID LIKE '".$Name."' AND SapID LIKE 
'".$SapID."'";
$result = $dbh->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch();
if($row == null){
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   echo "<div id='label-text'>Please check your UserID and SapID. If correct 
  mail/ping Anti21</div>";
  }
} 
else {

$sql1 = 
    "INSERT INTO Table1 (Change,WaiverID,Support,Reviewer,INC_RITM,Attachment,SapID,Schedule,ChangeType,AffectedCI,Risk,Ref,Priority,Environment) " .
    "VALUES ('" .$Change. "','" .$Waiver. "','" .$Support. "','" .$Name. "','" .$Inc. "','" .$Attachment. "','" .$SapID. "','" .$Schedule. "','" .$ChangeType. "','" .$AffectedCI. "','" .$Risk. "','" .$Ref. "','" .$Priority. "','" .$Environment. "')";


$dbh->query($sql1);
echo "Done.\r\n";
}
}
?>
```

EDIT: So I disabled Windows Authentication and switch to Anonymous Authentication and it starts working. Therefore the issue seems to lie with Windows Authentication. I have given All access to IIS_IUSR on the folder where the website and database is kept. I also gave individual user full control rights to the folder and shared the folder. That did not work. Still looking for a solution.

EDIT2: So I tested it with my id on a different PC where the DB file is not stored. It worked with my id. This leads me to believe that the issue is with permissions probably. I just need to figure out where.

EDIT3: I need to add users who want to make changes to the group IIS_ISURS. Once I added them to the Group, the site stopped giving error.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using PDO, take advantage of [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [bindparam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [bindvalue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php). **This will fix any quoting issues you may be having**  You can also try echoing the query and run it directly to see where the issue may lie.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am inside a VPN already and only authorized people would be able to access so it is not a priority right now. The main problem is that from the PC where the site is running this code works. But if I try it from other PC it gives me that error. So I think it is about some permissions somewhere. I may be wrong.

Comment: Which line is 139?

Comment: Echoing run gives INSERT INTO Table1 (Change,WaiverID,Support,Reviewer,INC_RITM,Attachment,SapID,Schedule,ChangeType,AffectedCI,Risk,Ref,Priority,Environment) VALUES ('ygeuysegr','sgf','jhgdfjshgjhg','username','jhgsdjfhgsdjgf','jhgsdjhgfsdhgfj','51523232','hgjfhgsdjfhgsjdfh','jhgfsdjhgfjhsdgf','jhgsdjgfjgf','jhgfsdjgfsjgf','jhgfsdjgfsjdfhg','jhgjhsdgfjh','hjgjhsdgfjhg`') Done.

Comment: $dbh->query($sql1);

This is line 139

Comment: Try adding backticks to your column names: `\`Change\`, \`WaiverID\`` and see if that helps. Security may not be a priority, but let me tell you, doing it the right way now saves you headaches down the road, especially when quoting comes into play. What if the reviewer's last name was `O'Malley`?

Comment: I have used the userid used in the organisation which is simple alphanumeric code like jriley1 or psamfo3 so that is not an issue again. It also helps me if I need to generate reports as I can directly relate them in Excel. I will definitely implement the protection from SQL Injection cause you are right cause what if someone decides to have fun or a disgruntled employee. It can be traced as Windows Authentication will provide logs as you said better safe than sorry. You want me to add ticks to column names on DB? Can you elaborate on the logic behind?

Comment: It's in case any of the column names are keywords or reserved words. My IDE flashed up for `Change` and `Schedule`, but the error highlighting is set for MySQL instead of MS Access. `Operation must use an updateable query` looks like it doesn't like the insert query, though I'm not sure why it says `updateable`.

Comment: Other links that might help [link](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/74/solving-the-operation-must-use-an-updateable-query-error), [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/175168/asp-returns-operation-must-use-an-updateable-query-error), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749572/access-db-operation-must-use-an-updateable-query)

Comment: Yes, I did not think of that. But the code works when running on the PC that houses Database file.On other PC it gives that error. So I think it would not be an issue. But still I will try it.

Comment: On a second thought, I think I would try by disabling Windows authentication and enabling default anonymous. Maybe that would fix it.

Comment: @aynber So I disabled Windows Authentication and gave all users authentication access in Authorization Rules. It worked. Going back to Windows Authentication Seems to be that Windows authentication is causing some issues. Then I checked by giving URL Authorization to all users and enabling Windows Authentication. Did not work. So cause of the issue is Windows Authentication.

Comment: Great, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Needed to add users who will be inserting data into DB to the group IIS_ISURS. Once I added them to the Group, the site stopped giving error.