# unhandled exception has occurred while adding data

Tags: c#

I posted a question earlier but I was not sufficient enough to answer. I am new to this, so my excuses if questions is not correct.

1. made a windows forms application on local laptop with a access database. It works fine. I can add, delete, alter and search data.
2. I have transeferred application qvb.exe and database in map on a testserver.
3. If I open the application I can add, delete, alter and search data. No problem.
4. If a collegae opens the application he can not add, delete, alter and search data. He's getting a unhandled execption error. See picture and error discription added.
5. The weird thing is that if executable and access database is copied from the server onto the colleagues laptop database it works.

Question: Why is the unhandled exeption occuring on the testserver?
(colleagues and myself are local admins on that server)

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Operation must use an updateable query.
> at QVB.qvblogDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(qvblogDataSet dataSet)
> at QVB.qvb.qvblogBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
> at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
> at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33zqC.jpg)

> ************** Loaded Assemblies **************
> mscorlib
> Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 4.8.4180.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll

> QVB
> Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
> CodeBase: file:///D:/QVB3/QVB.exe

> System.Windows.Forms
> Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 4.8.4150.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
> CodeBase: >file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll

> System
> Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 4.8.4001.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll

> System.Drawing
> Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll

> System.Configuration
> Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 4.8.4190.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll

> System.Core
> Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 4.8.4180.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll

> System.Xml
> Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll

> System.Data
> Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 4.8.4190.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll

> System.Data.DataSetExtensions
> Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
> CodeBase: >file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.d>ll

> System.Numerics
> Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll

> Accessibility
> Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll

> System.Transactions
> Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll

> System.EnterpriseServices
> Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
> CodeBase: >file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging enabled.

For example:

> 

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.

If you need more? let me know!
thanx. Ron

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access DB: Operation must use an updateable query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749572/access-db-operation-must-use-an-updateable-query)

Comment: Although you did not explain how you and your colleague access the program and/or the database, this does sound like a permissions-related issue (see the linked post). If not, we need to see your connection string, the parts of the code that are responsible for fetching and updating data.

Comment: The weird thing is: my colleague and I are opening the appliction from a folder on the d:\ drive. We are both local admins on that server. Like I wrote; I can do everything while he can search access database from a searchquery. He is able to enter data in the fields but when he wants to update it comes with this error. So, I am confused. The application is working. Is on drive where we all have access to and we are all admins. On that map on d:\ drive we have full access. If the colleague  copies this map or two files onto his own hdd it works. Question: why not on the server?

Comment: Just because you're a local admin doesn't necessarily mean you have `Full Control` permission. Doublecheck if your colleague's account has write access to the folder and the database file because it really sounds like it doesn't.

Comment: I changed the user permissions on the map as well as on the access database. We can't check earlier than monday. I don't know how long a thread is kept open before closed. If still open I will give the results over here.

Comment: In this thread they are talking about a bug: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833923/error-system-data-oledb-oledbexception-0x80004005-the-following-query-has-b    I am on 2017 community visual studio.

Comment: Changing permissions on the server map solved the problem. Everybody thanks for your input. Gr. Ron